# Serving Multiple Clients

Tags: java, client-server, serversocket

I wonder if it is really possible for a simple server program using server socket can handle multiple clients at the same time simultaneously?
I am creating a server program that needs to handle multiple clients. With the same port number. But the problem is the program will only serve one client at a time, and in order for it to serve the other client, the first connection have to be terminated.

Here is the code:

```
try{

        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(PORT);
        System.out.println("Server Running...");
        while(true){
            Socket socket = server.accept();
            System.out.println("Connection from:"+socket.getInetAddress());
            Scanner in = new Scanner (socket.getInputStream());
            PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

Is there any possible java code that will be added here in order to for the program to serve multiple clients simultaneously?

Comment: Look at Asynchronous sockets: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/io/example/

Answer (score 1):

The code you've posted doesn't actually *do* anything with the client connection, which makes it hard to help you. But yes, it's entirely possible for a server to handle multiple concurrent connections.

My guess is that the problem is that you're doing everything on a single thread, with synchronous IO. That means that while you're waiting for data from the existing client, you're not accepting new connections. Typically a server takes one of two approaches:

- Starting a thread (or reusing one from a thread pool) when it accepts a connection, and letting that thread deal with that connection exclusive.
- Using asynchronous IO to do everything on a single thread (or a small number of threads).

The latter approach can be more efficient, but it also significantly more complicated. I'd suggest you use a "thread per connection" approach to start with. While you're experimenting, you can simply start a brand new `Thread` each time a client connects - but for production use, you'd use an `ExecutorService` or something similar, in order to reuse threads.

Note that depending on what kind of server you're building, all of this may well be done for you in third party libraries.